# How to generate json string in required format in JAVA?

Tags: java, json

I need to generate the JSON string in following format:

```
[{"param1":"value1","param2":"value2"},{"param1":"value3","param2":"value4"}]
```

I tried to store data in following way:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = JSONArray();

HashMap<String, String> hmap = new HashMap<String, String>();
hmap.put("param1", "value1");
hmap.put("param2", "value2");
jsonArray.add(hmap);

hmap = new HashMap<String, String>();
hmap.put("param1", "value3");
hmap.put("param2", "value4");
jsonArray.add(hmap);

System.out.print(jsonArray.toString());
```

But it generated the json string in following format:

```
["{param1:value1,param2:value2}", "{param1:value3,param2:value4}"]
```

What changes are need to get the string in required format?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11143363/1007273  +  http://json.org/java/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. Use JSONObject instead of a map and add them to JSONArray.

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

JSONObject jsonObject1= new JSONObject();
JSONObject jsonObject2= new JSONObject();

jsonObject1.put("param1", "value1");
jsonObject1.put("param2", "value2");
jsonArray.add(jsonObject1);


jsonObject2.put("param1", "value3");
jsonObject2.put("param2", "value4");
jsonArray.add(jsonObject2);

System.out.print(jsonArray.toString());
```

I would suggest a better alternative to use a third party library such as XStream, which does it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use Jettison and it will do exactly what you want

import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONArray;

public class JSONPrintTest extends TestCase{

```
public void testPrinting(){
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

    HashMap<String, String> hmap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    hmap.put("param1", "value1");
    hmap.put("param2", "value2");
    jsonArray.put(hmap);

    hmap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    hmap.put("param1", "value3");
    hmap.put("param2", "value4");
    jsonArray.put(hmap);

    System.out.print(jsonArray.toString());
}
```

}

Output:
[{"param1":"value1","param2":"value2"},{"param1":"value3","param2":"value4"}]