# How to add more key-value to JSONObject in Java?

Tags: java, android, json

How to add **more** key-value to an JSONObject? `put` adds one element to the object, I need to add more value with key. I know I can do it with for loop, but I need a one line solution.

In iOS there is two different method:

```
append(contentsOf:
append(newElement:
```

Comment: How do you create your JSONObject? I can help you if I know your exact implementation? Jackson?

Comment: Java is pretty broad, are you talking about Android? Or Which library are you using?

I believe it's probably something like .put("key", someValue);

Comment: The .put example is as far as I can recall the Android implementation

Comment: I have create an empty JSONObject.

Comment: There are already similar questions on SO, try reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11143363/add-data-to-jsonobject) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32906634/java-gson-add-multiple-data-in-json-object-using-gson).

Comment: Did you get it fixed now?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in my comment, you're looking for .put("key", value);

If you want to put an object/array in there, you can just use a JSONArray or JSONObject.
To get an object from an existing class I suggest to use something like GSON to serialize your object. It's simply not possible to put a custom object in there.